# Evaluate function is not returning correct answer?

Tags: python-3.x

User is taking input using command line argument and the user wants if user input integer then the user will get the sum, in another case if a user enters string, then the string will concatenate.

```py
    from sys import argv
    args=argv[1:]
    b=0
    for x in args:
        a = eval(x)
        b = b + a
        print('Entered values sum is:',b)
```

Comment: What is the problem here? and please fomat your code the correct way.

Comment: from sys import argv
args=argv[1:]
b=0
for x in args:
    a = eval(x)
    # print(type(a))
    b = b + a
print('Entered values sum is:',b) @ here is the code.

Comment: code is working fine for the integral value, but as user pass string, eval() is not returning correctly,